# .SetRange issue - no formula allowed?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a similar problem as the discussed as in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398081/vba-sort-by-selected-by-user-range/62692098).

Actually mine is even more simple.

My VBA code checks the last used row in a column which then defines a range for sorting.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim KeyR As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set KeyR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Range("E10:AS" & LastRow)


KeyR.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Sort.SortFields.Add _
Key:=Range("E10:AS" & LastRow), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Sort
    .SetRange = Range("E10:AS" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
   .Apply
End With
```

For some reason, my Excel (Office 365) gives me an error message #438 that I don't understand. And always in the **.SetRange expression**. It seems that my Excel does no allow any formula here - while I find many opposite examples like the discussed here.

Any hint is highly appreciated. Thank you! LE

Comment: `.SetRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Range("E10:AS" & LastRow)`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost").Sort
>     .SetRange = Range("E10:AS" & LastRow)
> ```

The `Sort` object being held by the `With` block here, belongs to the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost")` worksheet object, and expects to be given a `Range` *on that same sheet*.

> ```
>     .SetRange = Range("E10:AS" & LastRow)
> ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753167/1188513) for more details about how scoping and identifier resolution works in VBA, but long story short (and assuming the code is written in a standard procedural module), the `Range` member call here is being made against an *implicit* global object aptly named `[_Global]`, that dynamically (at run-time) gets *whatever the current `ActiveSheet` is*, and invokes its `Range` member.

If that very same exact identical code is written in a worksheet module, then the `Range` member call now resolves to `Me.Range`, so `Sheet1.Range` if it's in the `Sheet1` module, or `Sheet2.Range` if it's in the `Sheet2` module.

While implicit code appears "beginner-friendly" on the surface (see, so little code, so simple!), it quickly gets confusing and bug-prone: there's too much implicit code going on for the reader/maintainer to correctly infer *from the code alone* what's going on.

The solution is to always be explicit about which `Worksheet` objects you're working with - and we can do that by declaring (and using) a `Worksheet` local variable:

```
Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
Set summarySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost")

With summarySheet.Sort
    .SetRange = summarySheet.Range("E10:AS" & lastRow)
```

And now the code no longer implicitly refers to *whatever the active sheet is*.

[Rubberduck has an inspection that can warn you about this.](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) (<~ my website and pet open-source project :)

...now, that's not going to compile as-is, because `SetRange` is a *method*, not a *property* - what you have at the right-hand side of the assignment operator needs to become an argument to a member call, like this:

```
With summarySheet.Sort
    .SetRange summarySheet.Range("E10:AS" & lastRow)
```

Error 438 occurs when a late-bound member call is made against an object, and the object doesn't have that member; because of the `=` operator, VBA was looking for a `Property Let` member named `SetRange` (as per the syntax used to invoke the member), and couldn't find it. Without the `=` operator, it's looking for a `Sub` procedure by that name.

The problem moves from run-time to compile-time (that's better!) when you work off a `Worksheet` declared local variable, because `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_Cost")` returns an `Object`, not a `Worksheet` - so the resolution of any chained member calls are deferred to run-time (and that's implicit late-binding).

With a local `Worksheet` variable, the compiler is able to pick up that the `=` operator makes the code try to do something it can't do.